How to correctly configure Xdebug 3 on a VM with PHPStorm?
I'm using Windows 11 as my host machine and accessing a VM at IP 192.168.160.186:22 via SSH using PuTTY. My VM is set up with Xdebug 3, and I want to use it with PHPStorm. Despite the configurations, Xdebug is not working as expected. Here are the details of my setup:
Environment:

Host OS: Windows 11
Access method: SSH via PuTTY
VM IP: 192.168.160.186
VM OS: [Specify the VM OS, e.g., Ubuntu 20.04]
PHP version: [Specify the PHP version]
Xdebug version: 3.3.2
IDE: PHPStorm
Connection: VPN and proxy (both are correctly set up)

Xdebug Configuration in php.ini:
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.log = "/var/log/httpd/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.discover_client_host = false

Xdebug Information:

Step Debugger: ✔ enabled
IDE Key: PHPSTORM

Directives:

xdebug.client_host: 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port: 9003
xdebug.mode: debug
xdebug.start_with_request: yes
xdebug.log: /var/log/httpd/xdebug.log
xdebug.discover_client_host: Off

Despite these settings, Xdebug is not initiating the debugging session with PHPStorm. What am I missing in my configuration?

Steps Taken:

Verified that Xdebug is enabled by checking PHP info.
Ensured that PHPStorm is set to listen for Xdebug connections on port 9003.
Checked the Xdebug log for any errors (log file is empty).


Questions:

Are there any additional configurations required for Xdebug to work with PHPStorm?
Is there an issue with the client_host or discover_client_host settings considering my setup?
Any other suggestions to troubleshoot this issue?


Thank you for your assistance!


Have a look at Upgrading from Xdebug 2 to 3. Your configuration appears to include settings from both versions.

Yes it's an Xdebug 3 settings

The XDEBUG logfile should not be empty. Could you please verify/post your xdebug_info(); Change you the start method to xdebug.start_with_request="trigger"and add ?XDEBUG_SESSIONparameter to your querystring.

I don't have any connection between the VM and my host machine, when i ping all packages are lost, this connection is blocked by suprvisor, can this impact the connection to xdebug ?

Xdebug is the one that connects to a debug client (PhpStorm in your case). You need to make sure that the connection goes through. To test: enable the "green phone handle" in PhpStorm (start listening for debug connections), confirm it's listening with netstat or alike, then try connecting with telnet or alike from within your VM to your host OS.


Is there an issue with the client_host or discover_client_host settings considering my setup?

Yes. Xdebug needs to connect to the machine hosting your IDE. That won't be on 127.0.0.1, but on an IP address starting with 192.168.160 — likely 192.168.160.1, the gateway.
See if you can telnet from your VM to IP 192.168.160.1 on port 9003 — you'll likely not get useful information, but the connection should work.
I think in your case, setting xdebug.discover_client_host should also work, as it uses the HTTP headers of a web server request to find out this IP address for itself.
If you want to see what Xdebug is actually trying to do, set xdebug.log_level=11 in php.ini, it will create a lot of detail in /var/log/httpd/xdebug.log.

Thank you for your asnwer, i modified my question : i put the host IP but still can't connect xdebug
